# Combining Observations of dataframe hourly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe that looks similar to the following

```
Date                Measurement  Room
2014-02-03 12:48    0.50         23
2014-02-03 12:53    0.43         23
2014-02-03 12:59    0.21         23
2014-02-03 13:06    0.23         23
2014-02-03 13:13    0.10         23
...
```

I am trying to **sum** all of the measurements **by hour**. For example, in the above dataframe, we would have:

```
Date              Measurement
2014-02-03 12:00  1.14
2014-02-03 13:00  0.33
```

How could I accomplish this in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html?highlight=grouper#pandas.Grouper) with `freq='H'` here. Check out [`List of freq aliases here`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)

```
# df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) If `Date` is not already datetime.
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='H'))[['Measurement']].sum()

                     Measurement
Date                            
2014-02-03 12:00:00         1.14
2014-02-03 13:00:00         0.33
```

OR

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='H'))['Measurement'].sum().to_frame()
```

Comment: thanks for the useful response! How can I use this, so it doesn't sum the other columns too. For example, I edited the original dataframe in my post above to include the room number of the observation. I would not want to sum the room number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `resample`:

```
df.resample('H')['Measurement'].sum()
```